# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'instrument'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have installed python 2.7, Pyvisa1.4 and ni-visa5.4 and get an error on running the following code.

```
import visa

thermotron = visa.instrument("GPIB::30")
```

Error is

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'instrument'
```

how to solve this?

Comment: This error occurs when you try to access a function that doesn't exist. Can you link to the documentation that describes `visa.instrument`?

Comment: Did you write a file called `visa.py`? In this case you might be importing your local file instead of the library. Are you 100% you are using PyVisa 1.4 and not PyVisa 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're misusing the API. The [documentation for PyVisa](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) shows this as the correct usage:

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
my_instrument = rm.get_instrument('GPIB::14')
```

Comment: Actually PyVisa < 1.5 *does* have a `visa.instrument` function.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue. Earlier Resourcemanager was part of "visa" module. Now it is available in "pyvisa-py" module. Hence install "pyvisa-py" from online repo using command `pip install pyvisa-py`. If you dont want to change the exixting code just use `import pyvisa as visa`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem there is no ResourceManager() in visa module you have to import pyvisa instead

```
import pyvisa

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
my_instrument = rm.get_instrument('GPIB::30')
```